# select downloadble & virtual on select of particular product category in woo commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, virtual

i want downloadble & virtual option in woocommerce to be selected automatically on select of particular product category.
This is my code i don't know whats the issue

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_single_category_slug' );

function bbloomer_single_category_slug() {

if ( is`enter code here`_product_category( 'e-version-magazine') ) {
    add_filter('product_type_options', 'product_type_options_default_download');
    function product_type_options_default_download( $product_type_options ){
    if ( array_key_exists('downloadable', $product_type_options ) ) $product_type_options[ 'downloadable' ][ 'default' ] = 'yes';
    return $product_type_options;
}
    add_filter('product_type_options', 'product_type_options_default_virtual');
    function product_type_options_default_virtual( $product_type_options ){
    if ( array_key_exists('virtual', $product_type_options ) ) $product_type_options[ 'virtual' ][ 'default' ] = 'yes';
    return $product_type_options;
}
}

}
```

this code is selecting downloadable & virtual by default for add new product:

```
add_filter('product_type_options', 'product_type_options_default_download');
function product_type_options_default_download( $product_type_options ){
    if ( array_key_exists('downloadable', $product_type_options ) ) $product_type_options[ 'downloadable' ][ 'default' ] = 'yes';
    return $product_type_options;
}

add_filter('product_type_options', 'product_type_options_default_virtual');
function product_type_options_default_virtual( $product_type_options ){
    if ( array_key_exists('virtual', $product_type_options ) ) $product_type_options[ 'virtual' ][ 'default' ] = 'yes';
    return $product_type_options;
}
```

Comment: You want that in backend (admin) I suppose, when you set a specific product category for an existing product or a new product… right?